# Translation for plugin

Tags: translation

I modified a .po file, basically I opened as txt file and made the changes, however I uploaded it and is changes are not working.

I wonder if I need an special software for doing and generate a new .mo each time I make a change, or what am I missing?

Thank in advanced

Comment: This question is not **WordPress**-specific.

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15660147/2215124 There you will see the necessary steps to successfully translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do "msgfmt" using the command line tool to convert the .po to a .mo, that is what Wordpress (and all gettext compliant software) uses.

Answer (score 1):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress suggests various tools including http://www.poedit.net/ which I found made editing plugin language files a lot easier...

Comment: I've just been reminded of a handy plugin which might be also be worth a look: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/ although I haven't tried it....

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows you can use Poedit to edit this files and generate .MO files.

If you want to translate the best way is by creating a new "Catalog", with te correct name. Generating new files (i.e: pt_BR.po & pt_BR.mo), and keeping the original file.